# Syncing offline material with website using wget

Tags: wget

I am using wget on Mac OS to download a website. This website is updated once a while and I don't really want to download the whole website everytime it gets updated. is there anyway I can 'sort of' sync my offline material with the website?
I really appreciate your help

Comment: No help on this question?